# how to add arraylist in Jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<%=new Date() %>

<%
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("C");
al.add("A");
al.add("E");
al.add("B");
al.add("D");
al.add("F");
%>

    <select>
      <option value="<%=al%>"></option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code i want to add Arraylist in drop down in Jsp I dont know how to Bind arraylist in html obtion or drop down please help me i have tried Much but unable to do this .

Comment: Try not to use scriptlets in JSPs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED

Try this:

```
<%

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("C");
al.add("A");
al.add("E");
al.add("B");
al.add("D");
al.add("F");

%>

<select>
   <%  for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
           String option = (String)al.get(i);
   %>
   <option value="<%= option %>"><%= option %></option>
   <% } %>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was a typo, it is not a1 but al in _for(String option: al)_

Comment: still have Error With That

Comment: please u check Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String Error is coming

Comment: Its working Only memory allocate value is not displaying in Drop down

Comment: Edited again, try with this

Comment: when we are adding values in array list dynamically, it clears its old value. How to fix this

Answer (score 12):

You have to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<forEach>` to iterate through the elements and add it to the `select-option` . Probably make the `List` a scoped attribute . Populate the `List` object in the servlet, set it in `request/session` scope and forward the `request` to this JSP. Remember you can populate the `List` in the JSP itself and use `pageScope` to refer it , but that will be bad design in my opinion.

```
<select>
 <c:forEach var="element" items="${al}">
  <option value="${element}">${element}</option>
 </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Here , `al` is the name of the attribute which stores the `List` in probably `request` or `session` scope.

**Use JSTL in project :**

1. [Download](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) the *JSTL 1.2* jar .
2. Declare the taglib in JSP file for the [JSTL core taglib](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html).

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

---

If you want to use just the scriptlets(which is bad off course) :

```
<%

List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("C");
..........
...........

%>
<select>
  <%  for(String element: al) { %>
   <option value="<%=element%>"><%=element%></option>
  <% } %>
</select>
```

The above code will work if you have defined the `List` as `List<String>` , or else you need to cast the element to `String`.

Read [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: please update my code so that i can Put it i have tried am doing first time want to learn

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: I wonder if the above `for` statement is better than the `Iterator`.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav `Iterator` means more code to write in this case :P

Comment: In ur case same value is not displaying

Comment: @AmanKumar (1)If you want to learn then follow good practices and try to investigate , getting readymade copy-paste code won't help you. (2) If you want the `option` to display some text then keep the text inside `<option><%=element%></option>` !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Good answer (although OP just wanted a quick solution, that's why she/he chose my answer), there is something important about using the JSTL and the standard tags that you are missing to mention: you need to include a taglib directive at the beginning of the JSP. If you improve your answer with that directive, you'll have my upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the  tag in the core JSTL library.

Store the arraylist in pageScope.myList and loop as follows:

```
<select>
<c:forEach items="${pageScope.myList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
<option value='${item}'></option>
</c:forEach >
</select>
```

This is preferable than using scriptlets which are not considered good practice

Answer (score 1):

Try this: declare your arraylist in between `<%! … %>`

```
<%! ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); %>
```