# JSTL : HashMap vs List functionality

Tags: jsp, jstl, servlet-3.0

It is very easy to create HashMap in jsp using `<jsp:useBean>` and use it

```
<jsp:useBean id="abc" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <c:set target="${abc}" property="position" value="triggerBottom"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

On other hand, when it comes to ArrayList, it is not that easy. I have seen posts like [SOlink1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835061/add-values-to-arraylist-use-jstl) and [SOlink2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879564/how-to-add-arraylist-in-jsp) where people are using scriplet which bring another problem of using PageContext to get attributes.

I am not able to digest it that HaspMap is so easy to use in jstl but Arraylist is not. Am I missing something? Is there any easy way of creating Arraylist in jsp, without using scriplet, and use el to populate it (as we can do in hashmap).

I am using servlet-3.0 and JSP-2.2.

Comment: Answer depends on Servlet/JSP/EL version.

Comment: @BalusC I am using servlet3. Is JSP version/ EL version is different from Servlet version?

Comment: Can you upgrade to Servlet 3.1? (which is out for quite some time already btw, e.g. Tomcat 8+, WildFly 8+, GlassFish 4+, etc). It comes with EL 3.0 which natively supports declaring collections via pure EL syntax without need for a legacy jsp:useBean tag.

Comment: @BalusC for me it is not possible to upgrade to Servlet 3.1. I am part of much bigger team.  Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
Servlet Specification Version : 3.0 
JSP version : 2.2 is what we are using. Is there any nice way to use Arraylist without scriplet?